# Custom bootstrap slider indicator links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've changed my bootstrap carousel indicator links to image tiles that link off to a page. I've got some javascript that changes the slider on tile hover and when the tile is clicked it should take you to a new page.

To change the hover i have (which works fine)

```
$("#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li").hover(function(){
  var goto = Number( $(this).attr('data-slide-to') );
  $("#carousel-custom").carousel(goto);
});
```

And to change the page i have

```
$("#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li").click(function(){
  var url = $('.getLink').attr('href');
  window.location = url;
});
```

This currently just redirect back to the home page rather than to the new page from the link. The html for the a tag is

```
<a href="/venue-hire/test" class="getLink"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed - was referencing first slide

```
$("#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li").click(function(){
  var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  window.location = url;
});
```